# Proper Facebook login for website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to allow people to log onto our website using their Facebook account. I noticed that when I click the login we added, the window opens displaying a detailed message and has a button which says Play Game.

On other sites I've seen a pretty simple window such as on CNet with a Cancel and Okay button on the bottom.

Did I setup something incorrectly on Facebook that is causing mine to be more complex?

Comment: Yes - you set your Facebook application [as a game](http://i.imgur.com/B89YiYO.png).

Comment: We do offer games on our website which is why we selected that. We plan on using this for our FB app to allow people to play games but also want them to be able to log onto our website

Comment: But the application you have chosen is not itself a game. The only reason that it displays "play game" is because that is what you have selected. There is nothing you can do to change the inner workings of this functionality. You'll have to change the application type.